# Как через Math.min.apply получить минимальное значение кроме нуля?

Tags: javascript

Как получить минимальное значение не `0`, а `4` ?

То есть нужно минимальное значение кроме нуля

```js
let obj = {
  0: 124,
  1: 4,
  2: 14,
  3: 0,
  4: 32,
  5: 78,
};

let all = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){ return obj[key]; });
let min = Math.min.apply(null, all);
let max = Math.max.apply(null, all);

console.log(min, max);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так используйте `filter` и уберите нули

```js
let obj = {
  0: 124,
  1: 4,
  2: 14,
  3: 0,
  4: 32,
  5: 78,
};

let all = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]).filter(key => key != 0);
let min = Math.min.apply(null, all);
let max = Math.max.apply(null, all);

console.log(min, max);
```

Ну и изврата, если хочется решить только с помощью `map`Ж

```js
let obj = {
  0: 124,
  1: 4,
  2: 14,
  3: 0,
  4: 32,
  5: 78,
};

let min = Math.min(...Object.values(obj).map(value => value ? value : (Math.min(...Object.values(obj)) ?  Math.min(...Object.values(obj)) : Math.max(...Object.values(obj)))))
let max = Math.max(...Object.values(obj).map(value => value ? value : (Math.max(...Object.values(obj)) ?  Math.max(...Object.values(obj)) : Math.min(...Object.values(obj)))))

console.log(min, max)
```

Comment: Спасибо, совсем забыл про filter, думал что одним map можно было обойтись

Comment: можно и с `map` только, но для этого вам пришлось бы еще раз вызвать `map` уже зная `min` и `max` и заменить нули на `(min + max) / 2` и повторно вычислить `min` и `max`, но это знатный изврат

Comment: @Serge88, посмотрите - я приложил новое решение, где используется только `map` :)